# Why does my DSDT table is different from what I found online?

Tags: acpi

I have found a field in DSDT table where I want to modify from here
[http://www.ztex.de/misc/c2ctl.e.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130311051942/http://www.ztex.de/misc/c2ctl.e.html)
Generally, I want to modify the _PSS field about the processor so that I can have more frequency levels available in the CPUfreq driver interface.
I try to use this command to dissemble the DSDT table from my Desktop(Linux2.6.29,Intel CORE 2):

```
 cat /proc/acpi/dsdt > dsdt.aml 
 iasl -d dsdt.aml
```

Then I have a file dsdt.dsl as following(very long, so I just show the beginning of the file):

```
    /*
     * Intel ACPI Component Architecture
     * AML Disassembler version 20090123
     *
     * Disassembly of dsdt.aml, Mon May  6 20:41:40 2013
     *
     *
     * Original Table Header:
     *     Signature        "DSDT"
     *     Length           0x00003794 (14228)
     *     Revision         0x01 **** ACPI 1.0, no 64-bit math support
     *     Checksum         0x46
     *     OEM ID           "DELL"
     *     OEM Table ID     "dt_ex"
     *     OEM Revision     0x00001000 (4096)
     *     Compiler ID      "INTL"
     *     Compiler Version 0x20050624 (537200164)
     */
    DefinitionBlock ("dsdt.aml", "DSDT", 1, "DELL", "dt_ex", 0x00001000)
    {
        Method (DBIN, 0, NotSerialized)
        {
            Noop
        }
    
        Scope (\)
        {
            Device (_SB.VBTN)
...................
```

But I can not find the _PSS field as shown in the website I have given above. I do not know why? I am sure the current cpufreq driver shows 4 frequency levels available. So at least there should be something in the table showing this..right?
Has anybody here played with the DSDT table before? Thanks,

Comment: And even in the ACPI spec http://www.acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPIspec30a.pdf, I have seen the _PSS field (just search for PSS). Why doesn't my file have this....

Comment: The guys of the article actually said that you should *add* the _PSS object (among others). Secondly, of course you have none when that was only [introduced](https://web.archive.org/web/20140524140355/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn613943(v=vs.85).aspx) with ACPI 2.0 and your firmware clearly doesn't cut the mustard (though it could just be that you can toggle some compatibility setting in the BIOS to address that). And I'm not 100% sure they are related then, but after skimming here and there I found in `speedstep-lib.c` that the OS is also looking at some CPU MSR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other tables that contain ACPI methods and such, besides the primary DSDT there are also secondary SSDTs.

There are multiple ways to retrieve these tables. On my 3.9 kernel, there exist a `/sys/firmware/acpi/tables` directory:

```
$ ls /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/{DSDT,SSDT*}
/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/DSDT
/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/SSDT1
/sys/firmware/acpi/tables/SSDT2
# for i in /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/{DSDT,SSDT*}; do cp $i ${i##*/}.aml; done
$ iasl -d *.dat
```

If your kernel does not have that, you can also try acpidump (not from iasl, but the kernel source tree. [Example package for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/acpidump/)):

```
# acpidump > acpidump.txt
$ acpixtract acpidump.txt
$ iasl -d *.dat
```